# How to change notification pane image

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, custom-roms, notification-bar, customization, app-drawer

I've just installed an ICS Rom (HTC Nameless) which has background images in both the notification pane and app drawer. These images don't appear to be well planned, because I can't read anything very well on top of them.

I'd like to either change or remove both images, but don't have the faintest clue of where to start looking. I have tried a few apps that have utilities for this, but none of them seem to work. I know my way around the filesystem alright, so I would like to change them manually.

My device details are as such:
Phone: HTC Desire C
Rom: Nameless (ICS 4.0.3) v7.3 build 4
Rooted: yes

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd be very glad :)

Comment: That seems like a modification included in your ROM. If there's an easy way to change it, I think it'll be in the ROM settings app (A lot of big roms have their own settings app. not sure about Nameless)

Comment: Update - I've found the images in question, located in /system/app/systemui.apk (logically, along with the rest of the UI images)

I have extracted the all and fixed the images, but I'm not sure how to insert them into the apk now. Any advice?

Comment: Also, Nameless (as far as I know) does not include a rom-specific settings app. Frequently, I've noticed roms for the HTC Desire C are far from fully functional, as it's not a horribly popular device.

Comment: Since you solved it, please post your solution as an answer (then when you can, mark it as the accepted answer). That's how things work around here =). EDIT: Nevermind, apparently you can't.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Jeff Darcy](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/42658/jeff-darcy) ([original](https://android.stackexchange.com/revisions/54470/3)):

> This is what I did to fix it (without touching a PC). I used ES File
>   Explorer, and "Photo Editor" from the Play Store to accomplish this:
>
> 1. Copy the original apk (systemui.apk and Rosie.apk) to a writable folder
> 2. Using ES File Explorer, long press on the apk and choose 'extract'
> 3. Once the extraction is complete, find the image you want to change, under `res/drawable-mdpi`
> 4. Edit the image using Photo Editor (I just made it black), and overwrite the original.
> 5. Using ES File Explorer, recompress all of the files you got from the extraction, using the ZIP extension
> 6. Keep the original apk, renaming it to something like "systemui.apk.old"
> 7. Rename the new zip file to "SystemUI.apk", being sure to match the original apk file name in spelling and case.
> 8. Move your new SystemUI.apk to `/system/app`, overwriting the default
> 9. Reboot, and enjoy.
>
> Caution: this may not be the generally accepted method, and therefore
>   could potentially cause damage to your filesystem. Be sure to perform
>   a nandroid backup, and back up your original apks, JUST IN CASE.